# Chartboost + Swift + Xcode 6.3 : didFailToLoadInterstitial giving syntax error

Tags: iphone, swift, chartboost, xcode6.3

I used below chartboost swift code in Xcode 6.3 and getting error for didFailToLoadInterstitial line. I don't had this problem in Xcode 6.2. How to fix this in Xcode 6.3 ?

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) 
{        
    let kChartboostAppID = "5472ef8f04b01601a1a5814c";
    let kChartboostAppSignature = "5b6222426e68cda48669a1d4d8246d4c3d20db9c";

    Chartboost.startWithAppId(kChartboostAppID, appSignature: kChartboostAppSignature, delegate: self);
    Chartboost.cacheMoreApps(CBLocationHomeScreen)
}

class func showChartboostAds()
{
     Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocationHomeScreen);
}

func didFailToLoadInterstitial(location :CBLocation, withError error: CBLoadError)
{

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This builds for me on Chartbeat SDK  5.2.0:

```
func didFailToLoadInterstitial(location: String!, withError error: CBLoadError) {

}
```